# Using render_list to render only map extract

Tags: mapnik, rendering

I am trying to render an area where I have added an extract from the planet file with render_list. The command I am using is

```
render_list -x 159 -X 179 -y 160 -Y 410 -n 2 --socket=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock --min-zoom=10 --max-zoom=10
```

to render zoom level 10. I already rendered 0-9 zoom levels for the whole planet, but want to render only the areas where I imported maps for the bigger zoom levels.

Running the command above gives message "Starting 2 rendering threads" and stays for a long time without doing anything. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the command above was missing -all argument:

render_list **-all** -x 159 -X 179 -y 160 -Y 410 -n 2 --socket=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock --min-zoom=10 --max-zoom=10

Answer (score 3):

I have found that using renderd -f usually gives me very helpful clues into what is causing renderd to hang or shut itself off.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [script](https://github.com/alx77/render_list_geo.pl).
It uses *render_list* utility in proper way and converts geo coordinates (WGS-84) to tile coordinates on several zoom levels and generates many tiles in one round.

For example:

```
./render_list_geo.pl -n 2 -z 6 -Z 15 -x 21.8 -X 40.7 -y 44.03 -Y 52.6
```